# Angular 4 - Best way of unsubscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am curious on how am I suppose to unsubscribe all my subscriptions. I knew about the takeWhile() and takeUntil(). I find the takeUntil() more usable for me.

> as far as I understand, takeWhile() take effects after we get the data. then unsubscribe until the component is destroy.

Whats is the difference of using takeUntil() and not using it. just .unsubscribe()?

**without using takeUntil()**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscriptions = this._membersService.getMembers().subscribe(data => 
 this.members = data)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

**using takeUntil**

```
private destroyed$: Subject<{}> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
 this._membersService.getMembers().takeUntil(this.destroyed$).subscribe(data 
 => this.members = data)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
}
```

> also how can I determine If I unsubscribe successfully?

Comment: As far as I know, no difference. takeUntil / takeWhile are useful when there's many subscriptions. Both should do the same job. I don't understand your first highlighted paragraph, could you expand on it please?

Comment: how can I determine If I unsubscribe successfully - the only way I found is to add a console.log and watch the console.

Comment: on the first paragraph what I mean is using takeUntil() is almost the same with .unsubscribe() function. ahhhhh I see using takeUntil() I can declare multiple subscription and I can unsubscribe it once. I see now.. ..what will I put inside the console log?

Comment: Can log anything from within the subscribe, then see if it continues after component is destroyed. (Assuming it emits continuously).

Comment: I use this code console.log(this.destroyed$.next() ); inside ngOnDestroy it returns undefine. does it means the unsubscribe works?

Comment: You should most probably not unsubscribe at all: this service call seems to return an Observable emitting a single event and then completing. When the observable completes the observers are unsubscribed automatically. Same if it errors.

Comment: > You should most probably not unsubscribe at all. --> bad idea. You never know whether the stream is going to stay this way (unique event) nor how much time it's going to take. For example, if the stream for some reason takes 10 hours before emitting the value, and you destroy your component in the meantime 100 times, then you'll keep 100 subscriptions alive for nothing and throwing potential errors when the `next` comes up.

Comment: Hi edizonv - actually, what I do is just console.log a string (within the subscribe) and watch as subscriptions are received, then navigate to another page (which generally should destroy the component) - but this is only useful if the stream is emitting continuously. You can fake continuous emit by temporarily hooking up, say,  Observable.interval(1000). That should confirm the destroy mechanism. I don't know any other way to do so.

Comment: WRT to if you should unsubscribe or not, your code is in onInit and looks like it it only intended to emit once, so (I agree with Maxime) you can put an easy auto-unsubscribe on it by using `.take(1)`. No need to handle it in onDestroy.

Comment: Also note, you may just want to use the `_membersService.getMembers()` observable directly in the template with an `async` pipe. If so, Angular will take care of closing the implicit subscription.

Comment: @Maxime if you never know what a service does, you shouldn't use that service. A service is supposed to be documented, along with its return type, and the kind of observable it returns. In 99% of the cases, the returned Observable is a HTTP observable, which completes or errors long before the component is being destroyed. Even if, in some very rare case, the user destroys the component before the HTTP response comes back (which never takes 10 hours), then what's the big deal: the component will be eligible to GC a few milliseconds later.

Comment: @Maxime of course, in the very specific case you describe, unsubscribing is a good idea. But this case is not representative of the majority of cases. That said, I generally prefer using a resolver to load the data needed by a routing component, which solves the problem.

Comment: I know it's an edge case, but my point is: Always unsubscribe. You don't know how a method is going to evolve and whether it'll keep streaming only 1 value or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys.. i really appreciate it. @richard, yes I put the service in onInit() I also have a search function which will display data.. on members page first load ngonit triggers and display the data. Is it ok to place the service in oninit or in constructor? Ahhh I will use .take(1) if the service is use once only right?

Answer (score 16):

The main difference is the way of thinking... and the boilerplate.

Without `takeUntil`, when your file will grow in size and lines of code, you might end up with something like that:

```
private subscription1: Subscription;
private subscription2: Subscription;
private subscription3: Subscription;
private subscription4: Subscription;
private subscription5: Subscription;
private subscription6: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription1 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
  this.subscription2 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
  this.subscription3 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
  this.subscription4 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
  this.subscription5 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
  this.subscription6 = this.service.method().subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription1.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription2.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription3.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription4.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription5.unsubscribe();
  this.subscription6.unsubscribe();
}
```

Or, you might declare an array of subscriptions and push into it.

Both doesn't seem to be very handy and if you end up with many methods, containing subscriptions, you won't be able to see whether they're being unsubscribed or not if you don't scroll to the `ngOnDestroy`.

On the other hand, using a `Subject` is much more readable:

```
private onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
  this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroy$.next();
  this.onDestroy$.complete();
}
```

Even if subscriptions are divided across the whole file, you can just check whether `takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)` is present or not.

It's also closer to the idea of Rxjs and dealing with streams.

---

Now, to make sure something is being unsubscribed, you can just use the third argument of subscribe:

```
this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(
  onNext => ...,
  onError => ...,
  onComplete => console.log('stream has been completed')
);
```

If you don't like to put anything into the subscribe method, you could do that:

```
this.service.method().takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
.do({
  complete => console.log('stream has been completed')
})
.subscribe();
```

---

If you want to go further down the subject, you should read this excellent article by ***Ben Lesh***: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: I would like to recommend checking subscription in `ngOnDestroy()` before unsubscribing. Sometimes it could happen that your subscription might not be initialized based on some conditions not met.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan the whole point of my answer is not to use the subscription directly :) So you shouldn't have to worry about that at all.

Comment: I saw that below in your explanations, however, my reference was to your first block of code, which was using ` this.subscription1.unsubscribe()`.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use RxJS operators such as ***takeUntil()*** operator as is explained by @maxime1992, but ***takeUntil()*** isn't the only operator for the job you can use other RxJS operators as well for example ***takeWhile()***, ***first()***, ***elementAt()***, etc. You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://getgoingit.blogspot.com/2018/06/unsubscribing-observable-in-angular-2.html).