# get item in Oservable

Tags: angular, ngrx

I work with angular 4 and I discover the Observable notion ...

I have this object.

```
myobjects: Observable<MyObject[]>;
```

I would like found a object with the property name of my `object.name == 'titi'` for example and `return MyObject` and not `Observable` ...

```
let toto: MyObject; 
toto = this.myobjects.filter((tb: MyObject[], i: number) => {
                return tb[i].name=== "titi";
            }).
            subscribe((tbs: MyObject[]) => {
                toto = tbs;
            });
```

Is it possible ?
I don't find ..
I don't understand :(

Comment: You can do the filtering in subscribe method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with streams, you should avoid making side effects if possible. Instead of re-assigning it to a class variable, you should rather embrace the Observable pattern and do:

```
const selectedPers$ = this.personArray$
  .map(arr => arr.find(pers => pers.name === 'titi'))
  .filter(pers => !!pers);
```

And then in your view use the async pipe like that:

```
<p>The selected person is {{ selectedPers$ | async | json }}</p>
```

If you want to display for example the name and age of the person you might do:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedPers$ | async as selectedPers">
  <p>Person's name is: {{ selectedPers.name }}</p>
  <p>Person's age is: {{ selectedPers.age }}</p>
</div>
```

This way, every time your `personArray$` emits a new value, the selected pers will be updated.

Comment: in your case selectedPers$ is a Observable<pers> and not a pers seems to me

Comment: I know your question is about "how to extract it to a variable" but I'm advising you to embrace reactive programming as you're discovering observables "I discover the Observable notion". The more you go immutable, functionnal and reactive, the easiest it'll be to debug and create new things (once you understand how observables work).

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples about how to deal with observable in angular apps, good luck with all that :). But really, it's a fun part. A bit hard at first because it changes the way of thinking, but definitely an excellent pattern which helps a lot building frontend apps.

Comment: do you have a prefered url link to propose  ?

Comment: A good start on [Thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html), then you might want to read this thread on Github to know why it's still nice to keep an Observable for an HTTP request which only emits one value [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5876), on [Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables) too and last but not least, post by [Todd Motto](https://toddmotto.com/rxjs-observables-observers-operators).

Comment: After all that, you might want to keep the [rxjs documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) one click away. You **need** to understand how marble diagrams works. After that it might help you to play around with few operators in an [interactive way](http://rxmarbles.com/) and eventually read few examples [here](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35).

Comment: Thanks @lg0173 :). Glad to help. Also, I forgot to share a small project I've made: [Compose-Teams](https://github.com/maxime1992/compose-teams) which allows you to generate balanced teams. It's pretty simple and rely on rxjs + pattern smart/dumb components. Looking a bit into the code might give you ideas :). And later if you feel like digging into Redux+Rxjs ==> Ngrx you may want to take a look into [Pizza-Sync](https://github.com/maxime1992/pizza-sync) =D

Comment: thanks a lot before to help you ... I have to work :D ... and now I'm hungry for pizzaI :D

Answer (score 1):

All what u have to do is to subscribe in this `Observable` and get the array then filter the Array to get the value that u want then put its value in your object.

here is a simple solution :

```
myobjects: Observable<MyObject[]>;
let toto: MyObject; 
this.myobjects.subscribe( result => 
      let newArray = result.filter(object => object.name === 'titi');
      if(newArray.length === 1 ) 
         this.toto = newArray[0];
);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: It works but it's not the best way to do that. Also, note that you'd have to save the subscription into a class variable and call unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy` to avoid memory leaks. I'm not saying you shouldn't do that, but for this use case, you should take a look to my answer which automatically unsubscribe when component is destroyed thanks to async  pipe.

Comment: If you want to go this way, you should take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801402/angular-4-best-way-of-unsubscribing/46805001#46805001)