# ngrx Store subscription is calling multiple times based on how many times we visited the page without refreshing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am implementing angular4 application with ngrx store.
I have a vehicle description page and list of vehicles page, on click of vehicle it will redirect to the description page.
Based on vehicle id I am dispatching store and later subscribing to it to display data like below,

**> this.store.dispatch(new LoadVdpTopSectionAction(this.vehicleId));

> this.store.select(state => state.vdpStoreData).subscribe(
>               (data) => {
>                   this.vdpState = data;
>               }
>           );**

Data is displaying correctly but the problem is if I go to description page 10 times from list page then suscribe is calling 10 times (debugger is coming 10 times to the vdpState variable).

Any solution will be helpful, Thank you

Comment: It's because you don't unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. Please see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801402/angular-4-best-way-of-unsubscribing/46805001#46805001

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the solution @Maxime